# https server using boost::asio (pion library) complains "no shared cipher"

Tags: c++, https, boost-asio

I'm using pion network library to write a HTTP(s) server, pion is a wrapper for boost::asio. I need the server support both HTTP and HTTPS, the HTTP is done with:

```
#include "pion/http/server.hpp"
#include "pion/http/response_writer.hpp"
using namespace pion; 
using namespace pion::http; 

struct fake_server {  
    void start() {
        m_server = pion::http::server_ptr(new pion::http::server(80));  
        m_server->add_resource("/", boost::bind(&fake_server::handle_request, this, _1, _2));  
        m_server->start();  
    }

    void handle_request(http::request_ptr& _httpRequest, tcp::connection_ptr& _tcpConn) {
        http::response_writer_ptr writer(  
            http::response_writer::create(  
                _tcpConn,
                *_httpRequest,
                boost::bind(&tcp::connection::finish, _tcpConn)));  
        http::response& r = writer->get_response();  
        writer->write("hello world");  
        writer->send();  
    }

    pion::http::server_ptr m_server;  
};  

int main() {

    fake_server svr;
    svr.start();

    while(1) {
        Sleep(0);
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to handle the HTTPS, I tried to set the port to 443, and set the ssl flag with:

```
    void start() {
        m_server = pion::http::server_ptr(new pion::http::server(443)); // 443
        m_server->set_ssl_flag(true); // ssl flag
        m_server->add_resource("/", boost::bind(&fake_server::handle_request, this, _1, _2));  
        m_server->start();  
    }
```

It doesn't work, I got an error "**no shared cipher**", I googled for this error and found some solution that uses openssl to generate cert pairs and then load these cert pairs in the server/client, but my client application is web browser, the browser won't use these generated certifications.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an SSL certificate and key the server will use to negotiate the secure connection. This would be done with:

```
m_server->set_ssl_key_file(pem_filename);
```

where `pem_filename` is the name of a PEM formatted file containing both an SSL certificate and key. The key must not be encrypted. There are numerous internet tutorials that tell you how to create a self-signed certificate if you don't already have one from a trusted certificate authority. If you have a key and certificate in separate files then simply concatenate them into a single file.

No prior certificate/key configuration is necessary on the client side (in this case), but note that using a self-signed certificate (or any certificate not signed by a trusted certificate authority) will generate a security warning on most web browsers.